# Derivative of (the length of) the Ricci tensor

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I was wondering, have you ever seen a formula in the Riemannian (more specially Kahlerian but not essential) setting for the derivative $X \cdot |Ric|^2 = 2 g(\nabla_X Ric, Ric)$ for a vector field $X$?

Or more in general $\nabla_X Ric$.

Thank you

David

Comment: You should add some motivation for what you would like in an answer. Is the manifold under consideration "special"? For example, there is a useful formula in the case of Ricci solitons, if $X$ is the soliton vector field.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I am in the compact Kahler setting of real dimension $\geq 4$. What is the soliton formula you are talking about? I am indeed in the Kahler-Ricci soliton setting. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't find a proper reference off the top of my head (will try to do so later) but you can derive it yourself: in this case $D_X \Ric$ is the same as the time derivative of $\Ric$ under Ricci flow (because $X$ is the soliton potential), so you can find/derive a formula for $D_X \Ric$ using this point of view.

Comment: ok, I found somewhere its used: see the first displayed equation in the proof of Proposition 2.3 of Brendle's high dimensional Bryant soliton uniqueness result http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.0270v3.pdf. There's no proof, but the proof is exactly what I described above (you should try to work this out yourself, its a very useful thing to understand if you're studying Ricci solitons).

Comment: If $g$ is my soliton with real field $V$ and $h(t)$ is its associated solution of the Ricci flow, you mean that the time derivative of $Ric_{h(t)}$ is $\nabla_V Ric_g$?

Comment: Could someone clarify what exactly the question is?

Comment: The question arose because I found on a physics forum the formula $\nabla_X Ric = \frac 1 2 X \cdot R g$ which stinks a little to me and I was wondering about it. Probably they meant $\nabla_a R_{ab}$ and not $\nabla_c R_{ab}$.

Comment: Hi David, the equation on the physics forum could be a misuse of $div(Ric) = \frac 12 dR$ (the contracted Bianchi identity) paired with $X$. Surely, the equation you wrote down is false in general, as otherwise it would imply that a metric with constant scalar curvature always has parallel Ricci.

Comment: Re: David Petrecca's last comment: Is it possible that they were assuming that $g$ satisfies $\operatorname{Ric}-\frac{1}{2}Rg=0$ (and that $g$ is Lorentzian)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments section was getting unwieldy, so I'll answer here. Hopefully this is helpful.

---

What I was trying to say is as follows: suppose that $(M,g,X)$ is a steady gradient soliton, i.e.
$$
\mathcal{L}_X(g) = 2 Ric_g
$$
for $X=\nabla f$ for some function $f$. Then, let $\Phi_t$ denote the flow of $-X$. You may check that $h(t) :=\Phi^*_tg$ is a solution to the Ricci flow. Then, the Ricci curvature of $h(t)$ is 
$$
Ric_{h(t)} = Ric_{\Phi_t^*g} = \Phi_t^*Ric_g.
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{d}{dt} Ric_{h(t)} = -\mathcal{L}_X Ric_g
$$
Now, relating $\mathcal{L}_X Ric_g$ to $D_X Ric_g$ in the usual way:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_X Ric(V,W) & = X(Ric(V,W))-Ric([X,V],W)-Ric(V,[X,W])\\
& = D_X Ric(V,W) +Ric(D_XV-[X,V],W)+Ric(V,D_X W -[X,W])\\
& = D_X Ric(V,W) +Ric(D_VX,W)+Ric(V,D_WX)
\end{align*}
and using the formula for $\frac{d}{dt} Ric_{h(t)}$ under the Ricci flow, you may find an equation for $D_X Ric$ (for example, it is the equation found in the paper of Brendle's I linked above; I've matched his sign conventions with $X$).

---

EDIT:  I'm going to work out the computation: I have specialized to gradient solitons (I'm not sure what happens if you drop this assumption).

From Topping's notes http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseq/topping_RF_mar06.pdf, we know that
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} Ric_{h(t)}(V,W) & = \Delta Ric_{h(t)} (V,W) - 2<Ric_{h(t)}(V),Ric_{h(t)}(W)>_{h(t)} \\
& \qquad + 2<Rm_{h(t)}(X,\cdot,V,\cdot),Ric_{h(t)}>_{h(t)}.
\end{align*}
If we specialize to $t=0$, then this gives us an equation for $\frac {d}{dt}Ric_{h(t)}|_{t=0}$ in terms of $g$-quantities.

On the other hand, notice that (here, we're using the gradient assumption)
$$
DX = D^2f = \frac 12 \mathcal{L}_X g = Ric_g.
$$
Thus 
$$
D_V X= Ric_g(V).
$$

Now, you can put the $\frac{d}{dt}Ric_{h(t)}|_t=0$ computation together with the $\mathcal{L}_XRic_g$ computation to see
\begin{align*}
D_X Ric_g (V,W) & = \mathcal{L}_X Ric(V,W) -Ric_g(D_VX,W)-Ric_g(V,D_WX)\\
& = -\frac{d}{dt} Ric_{h(t)}|_{t=0}(V,W)-2<Ric_g(V),Ric_g(W)>\\
& =  \Delta Ric_{g} (V,W) + 2<Rm_{g}(X,\cdot,V,\cdot),Ric_{g}>_{g}.
\end{align*}

This is the equation that Brendle uses in the linked article.

---

By the way, you can simplify the above argument by using the Uhlenbeck trick (if you work through the details of what I did above, you'll see that there is a good deal of cancellation, which you can exploit by using $D_{\frac{d}{dt}}$ instead of the time derivative above. See, e.g. ch 6 of this book: http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/28/bok%253A978-3-642-16286-2.pdf?auth66=1385658655_8c41399e85b51a3addd04347ad203f0d&ext=.pdf among many other places.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{d}{dt}Ric_{h(t)} = \Delta_L Ric_{h(t)}$?

Comment: There should be an extra term: see Proposition 2.3.7 in Toppings notes: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseq/topping_RF_mar06.pdf

Comment: This proposition is about the derivative on a generic curve of metrics, while proposition 2.5.3 says there along the Ricci Flow there is only the Lichnerowicz laplacian.

Comment: Ack, sorry, you're right! Note that the $-2<Ric,Ric>$ term in the middle should disappear when you compute $D_X Ric$ (this happens from changing between the Lie derivative and the covariant derivative)

Comment: What do you mean? What I get by adding up the pieces is $\Delta R(h)_{ij} - 2 R(h)_i^a R(h)_j^b h_{ab} + R(h)^{ab} R(h)_{iajb} = - \nabla_X - Ric(\nabla_i V, \partial_j) - Ric(\partial_i, \nabla_j V)$. What is cancelled?

Comment: Anyway I believe this is for steady solitons only. What about shrinking?

Comment: I have clarified my answer (and fixed a sign error in the beginning FYI). Hope this helps!  You should work out the shrinker case yourself! It is basically the same computation, with just the changed $DX$ equation.

Comment: To summarize Otis Chodosh's answer and David Petrecca's first comment (if it
is not already clear): Assume completeness and $\operatorname{Ric}=\nabla
^{2}f$. By passing from the (static) gradient Ricci soliton structure to its
(dynamic) Ricci flow version, since $-2\operatorname{Ric}=\frac{\partial
}{\partial t}g=-\mathcal{L}_{\nabla f}g$, we have $\Delta_{L}%
\operatorname{Ric}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\operatorname{Ric}%
=-\mathcal{L}_{\nabla f}\operatorname{Ric}$, using the diffeomorphism
invariance of the Ricci tensor.